# Minimatch pattern that matches subdirs but also just single dirs

Tags: minimatch

I've got this pattern: `{components,components2,test}/**`

that matches:

```
components/test
test/this/thing
components/something
```

but I also want to match
`components2`

how would I modify my pattern to achieve that?